# Chkdsk for a specific directory or File !?!? The Syntax

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, bsod, chkdsk

I need help to `chkdsk` a specific Directory : `F:\GOG\*.*`
I am too stupid to understand the chkdsk sytax for file:
`CHKDSK [Volume[[Pfad]Dateiname]]] [/F] [/V] [/R] [/X] [/I] [/C] [/L[:Größe]][/B] [/scan] [/spotfix]`

=>  `CHKDSK [Volume[[direcory/path]Filename]]]`

`chkdsk F:\GOG\` or `F:\GOG\*` or `F:\GOG\.`

does not work. Does anybody know the exact syntax?

If there is no way, anybody knows of a tool for that or any Linux command to run from a Linux-Boot-USB-Drive?

The scenario:
running    `compact /exe:xpress16k /c /s /a /f /i`    on drive   `F:`    makes a Bluescreen under a directory in `F:\GOG`!

So I can not run compress and can pinpoint that Dir or File to delete or repair.

Going farther:
Is it maybe an HD-Sector error for a specific file to run one of these tools:
[Is there an alternative to 'chkdsk'?](https://superuser.com/questions/46830/is-there-an-alternative-to-chkdsk)

For the records:
8 TB of Files (6TB used)
chkdsk /R or /B is not an option.

So I need 2021 answers and not 1999 ;)

Comment: See the [online help](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk).  Path and filename are only valid for FAT/FAT32 volumes.

Comment: first check your SMART stats to make sure the disk is healthy. then run chkdsk on the entire volume. it is not meant to be run on a file or folder. even on FAT32 volumes, all it will do is tell you if the file is fragmented. start with /f and then use /r if you still have issues. /r will take a long time to run. Never abort chkdsk.

Comment: Drive is fully ok. . Chkdsk /r is not an options as written. Taking off a whole 6TB game drive for 1x file or folder is not an option it is "we are still 1999 and have no solutions after 20 years of computing, High-performance, Virtualization and Quantum-Computers". More professional and detailed answers please. I am semi-pro and semi-pro answers are not a help.

Comment: The folder is named GOG, does this mean it contains games from GOG.com inside? Are there any games installed in that folder which are not from GOG? If yes may be you are having a collision with an game anti-pirate or anti-cheating system which has installed as driver and crashes if you try to compress it.

Comment: Very Interesting suggestion. No there should be no others, BUT I made a folder name GOG-Icons and put all Desktop-Icons of GoG in it [and yes it is the GoGames :)]. I am defraging the HD so far. After that I will move that folder and try again and report back. :)

Comment: THAT does not mea that you smart and program-aware ones are not allowed to find another better solution till my report back. Go on, find a file-checker or write a tool/utility.

Comment: @Robert: Just FYI if you are interested: I had FAF-Folder Hardlinked to E:. Compactor DID compresed it without any error! So I am very eager to find out if DT-Icons have impact on that for BOSD.

Comment: Use BlueScreenvVew to analyze them. Look especially at the stack trace and which drivers are involved.

Comment: Thx. Done that. it show only ntoskernal.  About the feedback. Moved the icons-dir, but that was not an issue. it some how managed to see the moment before BOSD. It was the gog/games/incoming. I deleted it, ran the compress, then it BOSDed on Ascent. I chkdsk /F after reboot, it showed no problems !!! I have a Donwload-Dir on the same disk, about 1,5TB with lots of really old and new very dangerous stuff in it ;)  NO PROBLEMS NO Virus-alerts no BOSD in compressing them... but a fucking GOG-Dir makes me so much trouble and no fucking tool on the planet to check the contents or integrity of it.